# Unable to install Java on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: java, 17.04

```
prakash@prakash-Lenovo-B40-80:~$ sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/javaTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 95, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 114, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 607, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 89, in get_sources
    (self.id, self.codename))
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Ubuntu/zesty
```

[image: this was the error]

I am unable to install Java on my Ubuntu 17.04. It is showing the error like in the above screenshot. I've been using Ubuntu for 4 months. Please show me the step-by-step procedure to solve it

Comment: Please copy and paste the texts from the missing picture!

Comment: i just added the image again could you please see that

Comment: Please do not put screenshots of text on the terminal. Copy the text from terminal and paste in in your question above. Format the text as `code` by selecting the text and clicking on the **{_}** icon above the Question editing window.

Comment: PLEASE COPY AND PASTE THE ERROR TEXTS!

Comment: yes i am trying to install orace-java8-installer

Comment: Sai I just added this key on Kubuntu 17.04. Please run `sudo apt install dist-upgrade`

Comment: hmm could you try `sudo apt install --reinstall software-properties-common` and then try the `add-apt-repository` command again?